# Is there any easy way to get AspectJ outputs in a file?

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

I am using Spring AOP with `@AspectJ` syntax in my project. May I know how to get the output in a file? Does any way to do that already exist?

Comment: a) are you using Spring AOP with @AspectJ syntax or static compilation with ajc. b) what is the output you want to log?

Comment: Yes ,I am using SpringAOP. I am annotated some methods with @Before ,After. I want to keep the contents of those methods in a file.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is very vague, it is hard to give you an exact answer.

But the intuitive way would be to add a logger from a logging framework like Log4J or LogBack (preferable accessed through SLF4J) in your aspect class and configure the appender to write to a separate file.

Or to separate things more cleanly, you may write a separate aspect that wraps the other aspect and does logging. But pay attention to [Advice Ordering](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering) if you do it that way.